# trying to automate translation on babelfish with python

Tags: python, http, utf-8

I have modified a python babelizer to help me to translate english to chinese.

```
## {{{ http://code.activestate.com/recipes/64937/ (r4)
# babelizer.py - API for simple access to babelfish.altavista.com.
#                Requires python 2.0 or better.
#
# See it in use at http://babel.MrFeinberg.com/

"""API for simple access to babelfish.altavista.com.

Summary:

    import babelizer

    print ' '.join(babelizer.available_languages)

    print babelizer.translate( 'How much is that doggie in the window?',
                               'English', 'French' )

    def babel_callback(phrase):
        print phrase
        sys.stdout.flush()

    babelizer.babelize( 'I love a reigning knight.',
                        'English', 'German',
                        callback = babel_callback )

available_languages
    A list of languages available for use with babelfish.

translate( phrase, from_lang, to_lang )
    Uses babelfish to translate phrase from from_lang to to_lang.

babelize(phrase, from_lang, through_lang, limit = 12, callback = None)
    Uses babelfish to translate back and forth between from_lang and
    through_lang until either no more changes occur in translation or
    limit iterations have been reached, whichever comes first.  Takes
    an optional callback function which should receive a single
    parameter, being the next translation.  Without the callback
    returns a list of successive translations.

It's only guaranteed to work if 'english' is one of the two languages
given to either of the translation methods.

Both translation methods throw exceptions which are all subclasses of
BabelizerError.  They include

LanguageNotAvailableError
    Thrown on an attempt to use an unknown language.

BabelfishChangedError
    Thrown when babelfish.altavista.com changes some detail of their
    layout, and babelizer can no longer parse the results or submit
    the correct form (a not infrequent occurance).

BabelizerIOError
    Thrown for various networking and IO errors.

Version: $Id: babelizer.py,v 1.4 2001/06/04 21:25:09 Administrator Exp $
Author: Jonathan Feinberg <jdf@pobox.com>
"""
import re, string, urllib
import httplib, urllib
import sys

"""
Various patterns I have encountered in looking for the babelfish result.
We try each of them in turn, based on the relative number of times I've
seen each of these patterns.  $1.00 to anyone who can provide a heuristic
for knowing which one to use.   This includes AltaVista employees.
"""
__where = [ re.compile(r'name=\"q\">([^<]*)'),
            re.compile(r'td bgcolor=white>([^<]*)'),
            re.compile(r'<\/strong><br>([^<]*)')
          ]
# <div id="result"><div style="padding:0.6em;">??</div></div>
__where = [ re.compile(r'<div id=\"result\"><div style=\"padding\:0\.6em\;\">(.*)<\/div><\/div>', re.U) ]

__languages = { 'english'   : 'en',
                'french'    : 'fr',
                'spanish'   : 'es',
                'german'    : 'de',
                'italian'   : 'it',
                'portugese' : 'pt',
                'chinese' : 'zh'
              }

"""
  All of the available language names.
"""
available_languages = [ x.title() for x in __languages.keys() ]

"""
  Calling translate() or babelize() can raise a BabelizerError
"""
class BabelizerError(Exception):
    pass

class LanguageNotAvailableError(BabelizerError):
    pass
class BabelfishChangedError(BabelizerError):
    pass
class BabelizerIOError(BabelizerError):
    pass

def saveHTML(txt):
    f = open('page.html', 'wb')
    f.write(txt)
    f.close()

def clean(text):
    return ' '.join(string.replace(text.strip(), "\n", ' ').split())

def translate(phrase, from_lang, to_lang):
    phrase = clean(phrase)
    try:
        from_code = __languages[from_lang.lower()]
        to_code = __languages[to_lang.lower()]
    except KeyError, lang:
        raise LanguageNotAvailableError(lang)
    html = ""
    try:
        params = urllib.urlencode({'ei':'UTF-8', 'doit':'done', 'fr':'bf-res', 'intl':'1' , 'tt':'urltext', 'trtext':phrase, 'lp' : from_code + '_' + to_code , 'btnTrTxt':'Translate'})
        headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/plain"}
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("babelfish.yahoo.com")
        conn.request("POST", "http://babelfish.yahoo.com/translate_txt", params, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        html = response.read()
        saveHTML(html)
        conn.close()
        #response = urllib.urlopen('http://babelfish.yahoo.com/translate_txt', params)
    except IOError, what:
        raise BabelizerIOError("Couldn't talk to server: %s" % what)
    #print html
    for regex in __where:
        match = regex.search(html)
        if match: 
            break
    if not match: 
        raise BabelfishChangedError("Can't recognize translated string.")
    return match.group(1)
    #return clean(match.group(1))

def babelize(phrase, from_language, through_language, limit = 12, callback = None):
    phrase = clean(phrase)
    seen = { phrase: 1 }
    if callback:
        callback(phrase)
    else:
        results = [ phrase ]
    flip = { from_language: through_language, through_language: from_language }
    next = from_language
    for i in range(limit):
        phrase = translate(phrase, next, flip[next])
        if seen.has_key(phrase): break
        seen[phrase] = 1
        if callback:
            callback(phrase)
        else:
            results.append(phrase)
        next = flip[next]
    if not callback: return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    def printer(x):
        print x
        sys.stdout.flush();


    babelize("I won't take that sort of treatment from you, or from your doggie!",
             'english', 'french', callback = printer)
## end of http://code.activestate.com/recipes/64937/ }}}
```

and the test code is

```
import babelizer
print ' '.join(babelizer.available_languages)
result = babelizer.translate( 'How much is that dog in the window?', 'English', 'chinese' )
f = open('result.txt', 'wb')
f.write(result)
f.close()
print result
```

The result is to be expected inside a  div block . I modded the script to save the html response . What I found is that all utf8 characters are turned to nul . Do I need take special care in treating the utf8 response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use:

```
import codecs
codecs.open
```

instead of plain open, in your:

```
saveHTML
```

method, to handle utf-8 docs. See the [Python Unicode Howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data) for a complete explanation.